# iphone facebook integration application response error

Tags: iphone, facebook

When I tried to post on wall of facebook in my iphone application I was getting the following message in the message dialog.

```
Application response error.
The attachment was either missing or its improperly formatted. you can see this because you are one of the developers of the app.
```

Here is the code I have used for posting on facebook wall

```
FBStreamDialog *dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.userMessagePrompt=@"Enter your message:";
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testing"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"AppName",@"caption",nil] dataParam:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"AppImage.png"],1.0)];
[dialog show];
```

Comment: Yes hanon edited my question and posted the code there itself

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer dialog.attachment is string that should be in a proper format having all the necessary fields like appname,hyperlink,description,media for images etc and properties. It wont be enough if it is just a simple string.

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"AppName\",""\"href\":\"Hyperlink\",\"description\"‌ ​ :\"DescriptionOfApp\",""\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",""\"src\":\"HyperlinkOfApp‌ ​ Image\",""\"href\":\"Hyperlink\"}],""\"properties\":{\"PropertiesIfAny":{\"text\"‌ ​:\"Property\",\"href\":\"Hyperlink\"}}}"];
```

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in the following code

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"AppName",@"caption",nil]
```

you should enter the value and key like this

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:value1,key1,value2,key2,...,nil]
```

Comment: No hanon... I've found the answer
dialog.attachment is string that should be in a proper format having all the necessary fields like appname,hyperlink,description,media for images etc and properties. It wont be enough if it is just a simple string.

    dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"AppName\",""\"href\":\"Hyperlink\",\"description\":\"DescriptionOfApp\",""\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",""\"src\":\"HyperlinkOfAppImage\",""\"href\":\"Hyperlink\"}],""\"properties\":{\"PropertiesIfAny":{\"text\":\"Property\",\"href\":\"Hyperlink\"}}}"];

Now its working fine. Thank u

Comment: Is this an older version of SDK? The newest sdk is more easy for handling the parameters.